# PRAW: inconsistent behavior when trying to monitor ups/downs

Tags: reddit, praw

I am trying to monitor a post, and plot the number of ups and downs over a 24 hour period (at 5 minute intervals). The core of the code looks like this:

```
while True:
   post = r.get_submission(submission_id='23a1zz')
   time.sleep(5)
   post.refresh()
   print post.ups
   time.sleep(5*60)
```

However, it does not reflect the true ups and downs. It's stuck at the same number even though the actual post is pretty dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

The API Guidelines state that the same resource shouldn't be requested more often than every 30 seconds. This guideline is backed by a cache, on both Reddit and PRAW's end that will return the same content if requested again within a short while. http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/faq.html#i-made-a-change-but-it-doesn-t-seem-to-have-an-effect